# Best diode for very high frequency (Vacuum?)

Tags: rf, diodes, rectifier, high-frequency, vacuum-tube

If we look at what's commercially available, the diodes with the highest maximum frequencies I can find are in the low GHz range, of the Schottky type.

I can also find research papers detailing geometric diodes, tiny graphene shapes which rectify AC, but these aren't commercially available yet anywhere, I think.

I recently learned about vacuum diodes - shouldn't they be able to work at ANY frequency? The efficiency may be lower, but to some degree they should always work, right?

Comment: It would probably be best to contact a company that can consult with you on this. For example, in the past I've consulted with Diodes, Inc, with some success. They (and other companies) have experts on these topics and they can help you a lot. If there isn't anything commercially available to their knowledge, they will just say so and suggest how they might approach making a custom device to meet specs. It sounds like you are in an area where you need access to people who ***specialize*** near the limits of tech. Use them. They usually want to help. This may be 'device physicist' territory.

Comment: Vacuum tube diodes can work fairly well at HF - like up to a few GHz for specially designed ones - but they still have inter-electrode capacitance so their HF performance is fundamentally limited.

Comment: @user_1818839 This capacitance means that the higher the frequency is, the more power is needed, right?

Comment: @jonn Thank you very much. I will do this.

Answer (score 3):

do you mean vacuum tube diodes, as your tags suggest?

No, they don't work at *any* frequency. In practice, their highest frequency is pretty limited (for those you can buy commercially), as your grandma's 1950 radio technician will tell you. They're speed is limited by the mobility (and inertia) of electron gas inside the tube, and by the fact that control voltages need to manipulate the potential / currents on rather massive scales. Have you seen how large a grid of a vacuum pentode is compared to the base of a bijunction transistor capable of the same currents?

Of course, there's highly specialized narrowband vacuum tube devices, especially used to generate high-powered microwave oscillations. But I doubt you're looking for a travelling wave tube for a high-powered satellite uplink or for a klystron to heat up your plasma for a fusion reactor...

Still, semiconductor devices are what you're aiming for if you're going for very high frequencies these days and ages – your 70 GHz automotive radar doesn't contain a vibration-sensitive, expensive, fragile, power-hungry vacuum tube! Neither do the Terahertz scanners at airports. It's all solid-state electronics.

It might be that you've simply been looking at the wrong type of devices – discrete diodes have limited bandwidth for package size reasons to begin with. Can't get Gigahertzes into something with a long lead! You'll find a lot of mixers, low-noise amplifier transistors, and other parts for the microwave RF ranges – after all, that's what's powering the current explosion of cm and mm wave devices. Don't be mistaken, though – you simply can't conduct a 70 GHz signal over a bog-normal glass fiber PCB into a diode in the size of multiple millimeters; physics won't have that. You need better substrates, other contacting, and so on. Things like millimeter-wave radars are commonly built as RF-circuitry-on-chip things, where everything from the antenna to the signal processing is on the same die.

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you Marcus! I will ask diode companies for solutions, now I know what to realistically expect.

Comment: I don't think you need to start asking diode companies at this point – I think you might need to read up on microwave engineering, either way (can't use a fast diode if you don't know your ways around transmission line effects on scale, anyway). And a good textbook would give you a bit of a perspective of what to use. I promise you probably don't need anything that you couldn't find via digikey, either, anytime soon. Like, you didn't even specify which frequency range you want to be working on – but brought up low-speed Schottky diodes. You're not looking at the bleeding edge stuff, honestly:)

Comment: Pozar's *Microwave Engineering* can be had very cheap used or in international editions, and would probably be a good start. It's not very common you'd *need* an RF diode in isolation. If you want to use it e.g. to frequency mix signals, you'd use an integrated balanced mixer circuit, instead, for example.

Answer (score 2):

There are many types of microwave diodes for all types of different linear and nonlinear, low and high power applications:

1. F multipliers : **Silicon Step Recovery Diodes**
2. Pulsing, phase
   shifting & modulation : **PIN, NIP**
3. Rx/Tx hi pwr : **PIN**
4. 20 GHz    Limiters: **PIN** oxide passivated silicon mesa type, low threshold

Other info

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIN_diode
NIP diodes: https://www.microsemi.com/product-directory/switching-attenuation-diodes/1807-si-high-speed-switching-nip